# ORMLite is it possible to batch updates by condition?

Tags: c#, orm

Basically, by this question I try to achieve this behavior:

```
List<Person> newPersons = ...;
connection.UpdateAll(newPersons, /*where clause*/);
```

Sql equivalent will be batch of updates for each person.
But, no results so far...